# three.js domElement vs using documentElement?

Tags: javascript, three.js

The THREE JS documentation states to use domElement as so...

```
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Is there a difference between this and using documentElement? It's mainly a curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

`document.documentElement` means `<html>`, `document.body` means `<body>`.
You cannot append visual elements into html.

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement